# Why is the character d printed when I assign a string literal to a char variable?

Tags: c, variables

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char a = "any"; //any string
    printf("%c", a);
    getch();
}
```

Why always `d` (for `%c`) or `100` (for `%d`) gets printed? What's happening?

Comment: Your code shouldn't compile.

Comment: Please note that `getch` is not a `C` standard library function. It is meant for machine running Windows.

Comment: Ok i got it. But now, why am i not getting a compiler error and why 'd' gets printed all the time? Can some one explain?

Comment: You probably just don't use your compiler properly. It should have a option such as `-Wall` to increase the warning level. If it really hasn't such an option, replace it by something decent.

Comment: @user3153907 It is because the string literal `"any"` gets evaluated to its address and then its implicitly converted to an integer. The least significant byte of the integer is assigned to `a`. It's just pure chance that that byte value happens to be the ascii code of the character `d` on your machine.

Answer (score 4):

`char a="any";` is not declaring any string. Your compiler should through error/warning. You need

```
const char *a = "any";
```

Now

```
printf("%c", *a);
```

will print character `a` as pointer `a` is pointer to the first element of the string literal `any`.

Comment: `char a = "any";` does, in fact, compile (though it produces a warning) and assigns `a` the least significant byte of the address of the string literal `"any"`.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has issues. On

```
char a="any";
```

the string literal "any" is a pointer but you are saving it in a (small) integer type. Because the value of a is (part of) an address it will have an essentially arbitrary value. On my machine it prints "T" (if I remove the getch() line because that doesn't compile).

GCC gives the following warning:

```
warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

and whatever compiler you are using probably tells you something similar. You should really take this warning seriously.

Comment: On my machine, it prints `/`. :) I get a `warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]`.

Comment: I use Devc++ compiler and it shows the same warning.
Sir, i cannot understand still. Why the string literal is a pointer here?

Comment: The string literal decays (implicitly converted) into a pointer to its first character in this case. There are other situations where a string behaves similarly.

Answer (score 0):

```
"something between double quotes"
```

Allocates memory for the string and returns a pointer to the string in memory. you need to store this pointer in `a` using `char *a = "abc";` now 'a' is a pointer to the string abc.

```
printf("%s",a) this will print the entire string abc.
```

for a single character use single quotes `'a'` in this case `char a = 'b';` is correct.

```
printf("%c",a) this will print b.
printf("%d",a) this will print the ascii value of 'b', which is 98
```

Comment: string is always null terminated. It's a part of its definition. So saying `null terminated string` is superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

In the statement

```
char a = "any";
```

the string literal `"any"` evaluates to the address of its first character which is of type `const char *`. Assigning a `const char *` to a `char` variable implicitly converts the pointer to an integer. This emits the following warning if you compile with `-W` gcc flag:

```
warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

What happens next is the least significant byte of the cast integer value is assigned to the `char` variable `a`. This is a random value and cannot be predicted. On my machine, it happened to be the ascii code for the character `/`. On your machine, it happened to be 100, the ascii code for the character `d`. It is just pure chance. Nothing else.

You should assign a string literal to a `const char *` as:

```
const char *a = "any";
```

and print the string pointed to by `a` by the `%s` conversion specifier as:

```
printf("%s\n", a);
```

Also note that `getch` is not a C standard library function, so your program won't compile on a linux machine. You can use `getchar` for the same effect, though.